# Kafka Connect - Handling delete table events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

we're currently in the process of syncing data from an Oracle database into a new PostreSQL instance.

For inserts/updates this works fine, but the deletes are problematic:

When something, like a customer gets deleted, the customer is removed from the customer table and moved into a customer_deleted table.

So I thought: I can listen on both tables to get the inserts, updates and deletes.

Then I would write a Kafka streams application which merges those two topics into one.

But that could result in a race condition, e.g. when an update happens after a delete.

So what would be a way to handle this? Maybe by joining the streams in a time window? Is this actually solvable at all?

P.S. I know of Debezium to capture deletes but 20k $ for the Golden Gate license is just too much for my case :(.

Comment: The right approach would be to write inserts and deletes into the same topic. Why is this not possible?

Comment: @Matthias But how do you make sure that updates don't happen after deletes, all being asynchronous?

Comment: You would need a single writer per topic partition to ensure order is preserved on write. All updates of one table should go into one partition.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax The problem is that I have two input topics, one for the COMPANY table, one for the COMPANY_DELETED table. Is there some way to write them in one topic ordered (maybe by timestamp)?

Comment: Not sure what your overall setup is, but when an insert happens on COMPANY table, you write a record to the corresponding topic. When a delete happens on COMPANY table, you should write a delete to the same topic (you can still insert the delete entry into COMPANY_DELETED, but this should be orthogonal on how you get deletes handled properly with regard to Kafka).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Sadly I don't get delete events in the COMPANY table because I'm using Connect JDBC (can't use Debezium because the DB is Oracle and we don't have a Golden Gate license :().

Comment: Is there any information that allows to recreate the original order (transaction.id? timestamp?)? For this case, you could write a program that reads both topics, and does a "merge sort" style merging of both to get one topic containing inserts and updates?

Comment: So I would have to read the complete topics? Or windowed? Would that work with a continuous steam of events?

Comment: Yes, you would read the both topics from beginning. Assuming that both topics are ordered, you just compare the first record of both topics to each other and write the smaller one to the output topic. As you only need to compare two records, this will work with a continuous stream: you might need to block if only one stream has data though, and wait until data become available for the other stream, too.